# Duplicate drive reported on MSA50

Tags: hp, hp-smart-array, hp-modular-smart-array

I am not sure why but whenever I install a drive in bay 1 or bay 2 of my MSA50, ACU reports that two drives are present in the bay:

[image: Duplicate drive in bay enclosure]

This does not happen to any other bay but bays 1 and 2.

The disc enclosure is connected to a SmartArray P812 controller fitted with the latest firmware and ACU is latest version as well.

Using a different port on the P812 does not help either.

Am I right in thinking this isn't supposed to happen?

EDIT:

Here the configuration details from ACU CLI:

```
=> ctrl all show config detail

Smart Array P812 in Slot 1
   Bus Interface: PCI
   Slot: 1
   Serial Number: PAGXQ0ARHZG0UJ
   Cache Serial Number: PBCDF0CRHZF03D
   RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Enabled
   Controller Status: OK
   Hardware Revision: C
   Firmware Version: 6.00-2
   Rebuild Priority: High
   Expand Priority: Medium
   Surface Scan Delay: 3 secs
   Surface Scan Mode: Idle
   Queue Depth: Automatic
   Monitor and Performance Delay: 60  min
   Elevator Sort: Enabled
   Degraded Performance Optimization: Disabled
   Inconsistency Repair Policy: Disabled
   Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
   Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
   Post Prompt Timeout: 15 secs
   Cache Board Present: True
   Cache Status: OK
   Cache Ratio: 75% Read / 25% Write
   Drive Write Cache: Disabled
   Total Cache Size: 1024 MB
   Total Cache Memory Available: 912 MB
   No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
   Cache Backup Power Source: Capacitors
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
   Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
   SATA NCQ Supported: True

   Array: A
      Interface Type: SATA
      Unused Space: 0  MB
      Status: OK
      MultiDomain Status: OK
      Array Type: Data



      Logical Drive: 1
         Size: 5.5 TB
         Fault Tolerance: 5
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 65535
         Strip Size: 512 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 1024 KB
         Status: OK
         MultiDomain Status: OK
         Caching:  Enabled
         Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Completed
         Unique Identifier: 600508B1001C7002145360DAB040A14E
         Disk Name: \\.\PhysicalDrive2 (Disk 2) (Bus: 0,Target: 4,Lun: 0)
         Mount Points: D:\ 5.5 TB
         Logical Drive Label: A2D3BB47PAGXQ0ARHZG0UJDCDB
         Drive Type: Data

      physicaldrive 1E:1:3
         Port: 1E
         Box: 1
         Bay: 3
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 3 TB
         Firmware Revision: 80.00A80
         Serial Number:      WD-WCC1T0563051
         Model: ATA     WDC WD30EFRX-68A
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 40
         Maximum Temperature (C): 57
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps

      physicaldrive 1E:1:4
         Port: 1E
         Box: 1
         Bay: 4
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 3 TB
         Firmware Revision: 80.00A80
         Serial Number:      WD-WCC1T0597161
         Model: ATA     WDC WD30EFRX-68A
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 37
         Maximum Temperature (C): 56
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps

      physicaldrive 1E:1:5
         Port: 1E
         Box: 1
         Bay: 5
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 3 TB
         Firmware Revision: 80.00A80
         Serial Number:      WD-WCC1T0579124
         Model: ATA     WDC WD30EFRX-68A
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 37
         Maximum Temperature (C): 52
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps


   Array: B
      Interface Type: SAS
      Unused Space: 0  MB
      Status: OK
      MultiDomain Status: OK
      Array Type: Data



      Logical Drive: 2
         Size: 68.3 GB
         Fault Tolerance: 0
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 17562
         Strip Size: 256 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 256 KB
         Status: OK
         MultiDomain Status: OK
         Caching:  Enabled
         Unique Identifier: 600508B1001C74235292BB43BA16138A
         Disk Name: \\.\PhysicalDrive3 (Disk 3) (Bus: 0,Target: 5,Lun: 0)
         Mount Points: None
         Drive Type: Data

      physicaldrive 1E:1:1
         Port: 1E
         Box: 1
         Bay: 1
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 72 GB
         Rotational Speed: 10000
         Firmware Revision: HPD0
         Serial Number: B365P7814WTU0735
         Model: HP      DG072A9BB7
         Current Temperature (C): 28
         Maximum Temperature (C): 56
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 3.0Gbps

      physicaldrive 1E:1:1
         Port: 1E
         Box: 1
         Bay: 1
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 72 GB
         Rotational Speed: 10000
         Firmware Revision: HPD0
         Serial Number: B365P7814WTU0735
         Model: HP      DG072A9BB7
         Current Temperature (C): 28
         Maximum Temperature (C): 56
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 3.0Gbps


   Expander 247
      Device Number: 247
      Firmware Version:   A
      WWID: 500508B300A0D30F
      Port: 1E
      Box: 1
      Vendor ID: HP

   Expander 247
      Device Number: 247
      Firmware Version:   A
      WWID: 500508B300A0D30F
      Port: 1E
      Box: 1
      Vendor ID: HP

   Expander 247
      Device Number: 247
      Firmware Version:   A
      WWID: 500508B300A0D30F
      Port: 1E
      Box: 1
      Vendor ID: HP

   SEP (Vendor ID HP, Model P812 INT EXP) 248
      Device Number: 248
      Firmware Version: 3.10
      WWID: 5001438010A1CAE5
      Vendor ID: HP
      Model: P812 INT EXP

   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model  SRC 8x6G) 249
      Device Number: 249
      Firmware Version: RevC
      WWID: 5001438010A1CAFF
      Vendor ID: PMCSIERA
      Model:  SRC 8x6G
```

Comment: What does `hpacucli "ctrl all show config detail"` or the BIOS ACU say?

Comment: Have you been able to do a restart and if so did the problem remain?

Comment: I've seen it before. It can happen.

Comment: @Chopper3 Yes, the problem remains even between power cycles.

Comment: @ewwhite Thanks for your input. It's good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this in situations where there are mismatched configurations... The P812 isn't *really* compatible with the MSA50. I've also seen this in cases where I had drive replacements/substitutions. Either way, you will not be able to see individual drive information, however alerts will indicate the proper slot if a disk fails.

An example... The array described below is 4 x 1TB drives in bays 0-3. However, they're reported as being in one bay. Annoying, yes...

```
[root@Twerk ~]# hpacucli ctrl all show config

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 50014380054E9DA0)

   array A (SAS, Unused Space: 522167  MB)


      logicaldrive 1 (72.0 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)
      logicaldrive 2 (1.5 TB, RAID 1+0, OK)

      physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SAS, 1 TB, OK)

   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model  SRC 8x6G) 250 (WWID: 50014380054E9DAF)
```